# Site em uma espécie de app

Tags: html5

Estou com uma curiosidade, uma operadora em Portugal(MEO) criou uma espécie de aplicativo em que conseguimos aceder a área de cliente, mas em vez de o instalar mos, no navegador fazemos login e clicamos no botão "Adicionar ao ecrã principal" e ele cria na home do telemóvel um ícone de acesso direto, mas ao contrário dos meus sites quando eu clico nesse Butão, ele gera na mesma um ícone mas quando abro aparece a barra do navegador e no da MEO isso já não acontece, inclusive quando vemos os apps abertos em vêz De aparecer o nome do navegador aparece "My MEO"

Como eu faço este tipo de site?

Comment: Poste o link para vermos !

Comment: Tudo descrito acima é PWA. Quando você abre um PWA pelo ícone pinado no desktop ou apps, ele abre o chrome em tela cheia automaticamente, justamente pra ficar com "cara de aplicativo". E dá pra funcionar offline, desde que você implemente os service workers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso se chama PWA (Progressive Web App), um conjunto de técnicas para desenvolver aplicações Web que adicionam progressivamente funcionalidades que antes só eram possíveis em apps nativos, ele uni o melhor da web com o melhor de uma aplicação nativa.

Vantagens:

- Rápido
- Seguro
- Envolvente
- Responsivo
- Usa menos dados
- Não necessita de conexão com rede (após instalado)
- Não necessita de uma loja de aplicativos nem baixar ou atualizar
- Um único código fonte para todas os sistemas (desktop, tablet e mobile)

Desvantagens:

- Os PWAs ainda não tem o controle total sobre o hardware do device: bluetooth, lista de contatos e NFC, são alguns exemplos de features que não conseguem ser acessadas pelos Progressive Web Apps
- Apesar de Google, Microsoft e Mozilla estarem apostando alto nos PWAs, a Apple ainda não está. Ainda existem duas features importantes não suportadas pelo Safari: push notifications e funcionamento offline. Mas, a Apple já está considerando implementar os PWAs, mesmo porque talvez ela não tenha muita escolha.

[Leia mais](https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/)

Comment: Não entendi o -1 que deram, mas é isso mesmo. Só precisa ver se não foi por copy & paste sem créditos  - eu tava respondendo, mas ia ser basicamente a mesma coisa que vc disse.

Comment: Por coincidência, essa semana eu fiz muitos testes com PWA.

Comment: Ahuahauaua, eu ja tinha essa resposta em uma outra pergunta (minha resposta), dai foi rapido

Comment: Talvez fosse o caso de fechar como duplicata? Tem o link fácil?

Comment: Não e duplicata, eu comentei sobre pwa na resposta de uma pergunta sobre proteção de código fonte

Comment: Na verdade é dup dessa aqui, achei agora https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/290719/70